# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [A] and [A] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/testurl] which is not permitted

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, servlets

I'm hoping someone can help me figure this one out:

I have two projects on my Eclipse (Spring Tool Suite 3 to be exact) setup:

- Our own project with our source code.
- Another project from a provider, which our project references as a dependency.

We execute the application locally using a Tomcat v8.5 server.

It was all working fine until recently, when I performed a git pull to update my local code and messed up everything (I'm not sure if I changed something else).
Now, when I try to execute the application, I get the following error (everything compiles and builds correctly):

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [A] and [A] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/XXXX] which is not permitted.

I didn't make a typo. The error message mentions **the same servlet twice**, treating it as if it was two different servlets that use the same url-pattern.

Searching for the servlet, I can only find it in a JAR that's downloaded into the local .m2 repository.
I mean, this isn't our servlet, it comes from the provider libraries.

I've seen the other answers to this problem, but those don't work here because:

1) I don't have two servlets steping on each other. There's only one.

2) I can't check if the servlet is defined on the web.xml and on an anotation because it's not ours, but it works for my colleagues so it should be correct.

3) As mentioned before, this servlet is loaded from a dependency, so I can't even try to change anything to try an understand what's happening.

Do you have any idea of what I may have wrong on my setup?
It works correctly for my colleagues, so it isn't a problem with the code.

I've deleted and setup everything from scratch (except deleting the Tomcat server); cleaned and updated the project several times, but I can't get rid of this.

My last attempt was purging and updating the local .m2 repository, but that didn't work either.

Any tips or ideas are much welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are declaring the servlet mapping both in web.xml and in an annotation, if i remember correctly some tomcat versions allow that.
You said it works for your collegues, check if you all have the same tomcat version.